# Informix Database triggers

Tags: database, triggers, informix

I'm trying to query triggers from "systriggers/systrigbody" informix system table. I need the data column of systrigbody table when datakey columns is 'A' and 'D', and should ignore the rest. Here's my code:

```
SELECT  tr.tabid, tr.trigid, tr.trigname, tr.owner, tb.data
FROM systriggers tr, systrigbody tb
WHERE tr.tabid = ?
AND tr.trigid = tb.trigid
AND tb.datakey != 'B' AND tb.datakey != 'H'AND tb.datakey !='S'
ORDER BY tb.datakey DESC
```

The problem I'm having is that it's returning data column only for 'A' datakey value, or only for 'D' (depending if ORDER BY is DESC, or ASC). I need them both. Any pointers?

Comment: Weird! Which version of Informix on which platform? It shouldn't make any difference, but why not `WHERE tb.datakey IN ('A', 'D')`? You should also plan to use the explicit join notation; it is better modern SQL style.

Comment: Im working on eclipse EE in windows 7. tbh, i dont know the version of informix. :/ I tried that.. Also tried "WHERE tb.datakey NOT IN ('B','H','S'). Doesn't seem to work either. Nothings seems to work, so i came here wondering if someone had a similar problem..

Comment: Not heard of such a problem.  Have you tried the query in DB-Access?  You must be using a programming language API because of the `?` placeholder.  It shouldn't make any odds, but ...

Comment: I haven't tried DB-Access. I am using JDBC api:
List<InformixTrigger> tableTriggerList = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[]
    { table.getId() }, new InformixTriggerRowMapper()); 
Thx for your help anyhow, and sorry for my late reply :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified your query slightly to (a) include the `tb.datakey` in the select list, and (b) omit the condition on `tabid` (so it picks up any trigger for any table):

```
SELECT  tr.tabid, tr.trigid, tr.trigname, tr.owner, tb.datakey, tb.data
FROM systriggers tr, systrigbody tb
WHERE {tr.tabid = ?}
{AND} tr.trigid = tb.trigid
AND tb.datakey != 'B' AND tb.datakey != 'H'AND tb.datakey !='S'
ORDER BY tb.datakey DESC;
```

I ran it on a database laden with triggers, and part of the output was:

```
124|49|u_timerecord|wtsdba|D|create trigger "wtsdba".u_timerecord update on "wtsdba".timerecord
124|50|d_timerecord|wtsdba|D|create trigger "wtsdba".d_timerecord delete on "wtsdba".timerecord
125|51|u_wi_buglist|wtsdba|D|create trigger "wtsdba".u_wi_buglist update on "wtsdba".wi_buglist
127|52|u_wi_problem|wtsdba|D|create trigger "wtsdba".u_wi_problem update on "wtsdba".wi_problem
128|53|u_wi_task|wtsdba|D|create trigger "wtsdba".u_wi_task update on "wtsdba".wi_task
106|15|d_workstate|wtsdba|A| before\ (\ execute procedure "jleffler".wtsdba_del('WorkState' ));
106|14|u_workstate|wtsdba|A| before\ (\ execute procedure "jleffler".wtsdba_upd('WorkState' ));
114|29|u_sec_action|wtsdba|A| before\ (\ execute procedure "jleffler".wtsdba_upd('SEC_Action' ));
107|16|d_workitem|wtsdba|A| before\ (\ execute procedure "jleffler".wtsdba_del('WorkItem' ));
115|30|u_wts_menu|wtsdba|A| before\ (\ execute procedure "jleffler".wtsdba_upd('WTS_Menu' ));
```

I munged the output so that multiple blanks were replaced by a single blank.  There were 110 lines in total; I simply selected a few from the middle of the list where the data key changed from `'D'` to `'A'`.

This was run in a DB-Access work (somewhat) alike; you'd get essentially the same result with DB-Access, but the formatting would be far more verbose.

From this, I deduce that your query is fundamentally sound.  I'm not disputing that you're seeing odd results.  So, you need to produce a minimal test case — a simple Java and JDBC program that executes the query shown, or your original query, and which demonstrates the problem (an SSCCE — [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) — in other words), to show how you see the problem.  We can then hope to reproduce the problem.  Please include the schema for a simple table with a trigger on it, so that we are working with the 'same' catalog data.

It would also help to find the version of Informix that you're using.  You should be able to use:

```
SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM SysTables WHERE TabID = 1;
```

If it fails because it isn't supported, your Informix is long out of support.  I got the output:

```
IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC6
```

I'm running on a Mac with Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: I got it working. Sry for the late reply, and thank you for your help. I Finally found my problem and it was in junit testing, didnt run the test just right. Im new to databases, informix. I tought my problem was query 'couse different sorting gave me different output. Turns out the query was solid. Was always 1 (of the 2 needed) missing. 
Thx again, and sorry for the trouble you've gone thru. :)